# Apache2 modules folder where is it?

Tags: apache2

I actually used to install, manipulate and configure apache on windows and ultimately install and configure new modules to my local server, and the case isn't the same on Ubuntu.

I installed apache2, but I still can't find the modules folder, I mean the structure that I got on my computer isn't the same  that I knew on windows!

- the path is this : `/etc/init.d/apache` this path is the `start|stop|restart|reload`.
- and the www directory is located here : `/var/www/*.html`

So, I am supposed to copy a module file that I got `mod_security2.so` to this location `/usr/local/apache/modules/`.
In my case I don't have this structure for apache folders

```
$ ls /etc/apache2
apache2.conf    envvars         mods-enabled     sites-enabled
conf-available  magic           ports.conf
conf-enabled    mods-available  sites-available
```

So where should I paste the module file knowing that the files inside `mods-enabled` are `*.load` and `*.so`.

Answer (score 10):

Be prepared to ditch a lot of what you know from Windows. In particular, to install the `security2` module, install `libapache2-mod-security2`:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-security2
```

The module shared library files go in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules`, not that you should use your own when there's a packaged version available.

Comment: Thank you @muru, I already compiled modsecurity from the source files, and yes you are totally right, the module library files is  in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules`, problem is solved and thanks again.